# Is it possible to return a hardcoded response in Ocelot API Gateway?

Tags: api-gateway, ocelot

In other api gateways, like Gloo, it is possible to create a route that instead of going downstream, it returns a "directResponseAction", like status = 200 and body = "hello".

Is it possible to do the same thing in Ocelot API Gateway?

To make it very clear, I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. User requests https://mygateway/hardcoded
2. Ocelot returns HTTP 200 "Hello" (no downstream host involved)